# Add System.Drawing.Common reference

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-core

I started to move one of my projects from .NET Framework to .NET Core (3.1) and I got a compiler error.

I have a class working with Bitmap but it can't be found in `System.Drawing`. VS was so kind to tell me that it was moved to `System.Drawing.Common` which is in system.drawing.common.dll.

Well... I can't add it as a reference bc I can't find it anywhere.
Where can I add the `System.Drawing.Common` namespace to my project?

Answer (score 4):

Install [the NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common) for it

Some pointers and background discussion: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouUseSystemDrawingInNETCore.aspx the essence of which (in case of link rot) is:

- Using System.Drawing of old was tied to Windows
- MS repackaged things as System.Drawing.Common, put it on NuGet and it works on core/linux
- You'll need to apt install some other dependencies on linux
- Consider using [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) instead if you're doing stuff like resizing images, filtering, distorting, drawing etc